# Lower and Upper bounds of $p_n\#$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, number-theory, prime-numbers, upper-lower-bounds

Between Wikipedia and other online sources I've found people give lower and upper bounds for $n\#$. But I've seen very little for bounds of $p_n\#$ or information about it? What's known about the bounds of $p_n\#$?

From [Cohen 2022](http://math.colgate.edu/%7Eintegers/w106/w106.pdf) he gives $p_{n!} < p_n\#$ but this isn't that useful.

Comment: One can combine the bounds you found for $k\#$, applied with $k=p_n$, with bounds for $p_n$ in terms of $n$ (which should be equally easy to find).

Comment: The prime number theorem and the Riemann hypothesis give pretty sharp bounds for $\log p_n\#$

Comment: @reuns Do you know where I could find them? Having trouble locating information

Comment: @NickArnold From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial): $$\log (p_n \#) = (1+o(1))n \log n$$ and asymptotically as we head toward infinity: $$\log (p_n \#) \sim n \log n$$